# Proving Russel paradox using Hilbert style deduction

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

On Wikipedia's entry for [Formal Presentation of Russel's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox#Formal_presentation), existential instantiation ("reusing the symbol y") is one of the two steps (the other being universal instantiation) employed to get from

$\exists y\forall x\ (x\in y \iff P(x))$

to

$y \in y \iff y \not\in  y$

I'm trying to see how this argument would look like in a Hilbert deduction system - in particular, what form would existential instantiation take? I've found one possible answer Carl Mummert gave [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/116995), where existential instantiation would be a metatheorem, and applied to this particular case with

$\phi(y) \equiv (\forall x\ (x\in y \iff P(x)))$

$\psi \equiv (y \in y \iff y \not\in  y)$,

the theorem would state that if $\phi(c)\vdash\psi$ then $(\exists y) \phi(y)\vdash \psi$.

The theorem also states that "there is a deduction witnessing this fact that does not mention $c$". What would be the explicit form of this deduction? I.e. how would we get from

$\exists y\forall x\ (x\in y \iff P(x))$

to

$y \in y \iff y \not\in  y$

using Hilbert style deduction only?

Answer (score 0):

For an Hilbert style deduction you need to state what the axiom(schemes) and inference rules of your system first

the axiom(scheme) for Existentional elimination is most times something like

ExPx -> ((Pt -> Q) -> Q) 
where Q may not contain t

Hilbert style proofs are most times also hoplessly long here a proof in natural deduction:

- 1 |     EyVx( x e y <-> P(x)). . . . . Premmisse
- 2 | |_t Vx( t e y <-> P(x)). . . . . New subproof
- 3 | |   Vx( t e y <-> ~(x e t)). .  . . 2 define P(X)
- 4 | |   t e t  <-> ~(t e t). . . . . . . . . 3 Universal elimination (or instantisation)
- 5 | |   Ez( z e z  <-> ~(z e z)) . . . 4 Existentional Introduction
- < | <------------------------------ end subproof
- 6 |     Ez( z e z  <-> ~(z e z)) . . . . . 1, 2-5 Existentional elimination
- 7 |     Ey( y e y  <-> ~(y e y)) . . . . 6 relettering

Sorry layouting it nice is a bit to complex for me

Hope this helps

Comment: Add `$\def\rule#1#2{\left|\!\!\begin{array}{l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}\right.}$` at the start of your answer and you can use `\rule{P}{Q}` to get "$\left|\!\!\begin{array}{l}P\\\hline Q\end{array}\right.$". However, your answer using ND does not address the question asking for Hilbert-style (although I agree that ND is much better).

Comment: Also, read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.